# What exactly is the converse and the reciprocal of the Pythagorean theorem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, advice

I think I spotted a translation problem at exercise 12 in Appendix B of Stewart's Calculus, 6th edition, the Portuguese version of the book.  Here's the original problem:

12. (a) Show that the triangle with vertices $A(6, -7)$, $B(11, -3)$ and $C(2, -2)$ is a right triangle using the converse of the Pythagorean Theorem. (b) Use slopes to show that $ABC$ is a right triangle. (c) Find the area of the triangle.

The translation however puts it this way: 12. (a) Show that the triangle with vertices $A(6, -7)$, $B(11, -3)$ and $C(2, -2)$ is a right triangle **using the reciprocal of the Pythagorean Theorem**.

These are two different theorems, aren't they?  The converse should be --- if the square of the hypotenuse equals the sum of the squares of the other sides, then there's a right angle in the triangle.  The reciprocal theorem says that $1/h^2 = 1/a^2 + 1/b^2$ where $h$ is the height of the triangle relative to the right-angle.

Or am I not quite understanding the essence of the exercise?  Please advise.

**The Portuguese version in Portuguese**. "12. (a) Mostre que o triângulo com vértices $A(6, -7)$, $B(11, -3)$ e $C(2, -2)$ é um triângulo retângulo usando a recíproca do Teorema de Pitágoras. (b) Use as inclinações para mostrar que $ABC$ é um triângulo retângulo. (c) Determine a área do triângulo."

Here's an image.

[image: Problem 12, Stewart's Calculus, appendix B, Portuguese version]

Comment: "Reciprocal" is the wrong translation. It should be "converse". The converse is that if a triangle with sides of length $a$, $b$, and $c$ satisfies that $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then it is a right triangle with hypothenuse of length $c$.

Comment: The translation is probably **in Portuguese**, no? What you're giving is a translation of a translation, and without knowing any details, my guess is that the answer should be "in context, that word in Portuguese means *converse*, not *reciprocal*". It doesn't even make sense to talk about the "reciprocal of a theorem" in English, and the fact that there's a related result sometimes (apparently) called the "reciprocal theorem" is probably a coincidence.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_She_Is_Spoke   Mark Twain said of English as She Is Spoke "Nobody can add to the absurdity of this book, nobody can imitate it successfully, nobody can hope to produce its fellow; it is perfect."

Stephen Pile mentions this work in The Book of Heroic Failures and comments: "Is there anything in conventional English which could equal the vividness of 'to craunch a marmoset'?"

Comment: @MishaLavrov, yes, the translation is in Portuguese.  I'm adding the Portuguese version to the question.  Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: @WillJagy, thanks for the literary tangent --- looks real interesting!

Comment: In Spanish, it might make sense to talk about the "reciprocal implication", to refer to the implication "if $B$ then $A$" being the reciprocal of "if $A$ then $B$". So I'm guessing the same might be true in Portuguese. But in English, one talks about the *converse* implication. It's just one of those things where there is a translation for the word, but it is the wrong word to use in context. Just like there was a time when in Spanish, electronic computers were called "ordenadores", but you wouldn't then translate that into "orderers", even though that is what the word means literally.

Comment: Very good point.  As matter of fact, this has just reversed my understanding.  In this [lecture](http://escolas.uevora.pt/eb23ar/pluginfile.php/5220/mod_resource/content/1/Th.%20Pit%C3%A1goras%20Sintese_escola%20virtual.pdf) "from Portugal", they call the converse of the theorem as "recíproco do Teorema de Pitágoras".  (Third paragraph, first page.)  This means there's no translation mistake.  It just my lack of Portuguese culture that fooled me.  (But now I wonder what the Portuguese people call the Reciprocal of Pythagorean Theorem, as it is called in the Anglophone world.

Comment: There is no "Reciprocal of Pythagorean Theorem" in the anglophone world.

Comment: Thank's for the question. It help me a lot. I speak portuguese and I had a very similar problem. I just think It should be in another cathegory of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we go to [the Portuguese Wikipedia article on the Pythagorean theorem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_Pit%C3%A1goras#Rec%C3%ADproca), we see the following:

> A recíproca do teorema de Pitágoras também é verdadeira: "Para qualquer triângulo com lados $l$, $m$, e $r$, se $l^2 + m^2 = r^2$, então o ângulo entre $l$ e $m$ mede $90^\circ$".

This tells us that the statement of "recíproca do teorema de Pitágoras" is what in English we call the converse to the Pythagorean theorem: if a triangle with side lengths $l$, $m$, and $r$ satisfies $l^2 + m^2 = r^2$, then the angle between the sides of lengths $l$ and $m$ is a right angle.

There is no mistake in the translation, and the use of "recíproca" has no relation to the English "reciprocal", nor to the theorem you are quoting as the "reciprocal theorem".

Note that in non-mathematical language, the word "reciprocal" refers to something done in return for a previous action, or something done in both directions. In English, the mathematical usage ended up with using "reciprocal" for the multiplicative inverse, and it appears that in Portuguese, the mathematical usage ended up with using the corresponding word for the converse, but it is easy to see how both are related to the original meaning.

In Portuguese, the multiplicative inverse appears to just be called [inverso multiplicativo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverso_multiplicativo), if we are to trust Wikipedia a second time. The word "recíproco" is only mentioned once, as a historical usage in a translation from English.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer.  I confirm the usage of "inverso multiplicativo" in Portuguese.  I'm now calling the reciprocal theorem simply as the inverse Pythagorean theorem.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1145880 Why would you call it by the wrong name? It's the **converse** of the Pythagorean Theorem, not the inverse.

Comment: I meant [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Pythagorean_theorem). "In geometry, the inverse Pythagorean theorem [is] also known as the reciprocal Pythagorean theorem or the upside down Pythagorean theorem".